# Saving to Online database and Localhost database

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to make a script when the Online Database is not available or the internet connection is interrupted it will save in the localhost database. I'm using PDO

This is what I'm trying to do

```
try
{
DBOnline (Insert values)
DBLocalhost(insert values)
}
catch(I dunno what to put here)
{
DB Localhost (save all)
}
```

Thank you Sir Mam

Answer (score 0):

Use this on declaring database connection

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($online_host, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($localhost, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $ee) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $ee->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir Can I try this?

I already initialize my connection string then

try {
    //Insert into database in online SQL Insert into 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    try {
         //Insert into database in Localhost SQL Insert into 
    } catch (PDOException $ee) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $ee->getMessage();
    }
}

is this right sir?

Comment: The code snippet makes your connection, to whichever host is available.  Your insert execution is the same regardless.